# Google Sign In gapi undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-api

I am trying to enable sign in with google on my site. The button works, syncs with my account, but I can not access the userId from google. This is what's in my head.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
      </script>
```

And this is where I'm trying to obtain the user Id. In the console I get the error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined.` I thought I was calling `gapi` in the source above. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
      'userId' : 'me'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      console.log('ID: ' + resp.id);
      console.log('Display Name: ' + resp.displayName);
      console.log('Image URL: ' + resp.image.url);
      console.log('Profile URL: ' + resp.url);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code is calling `gapi.client.plus.people.get` method before loading the google api library `https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js`. Hence you are getting gapi is not defined error.

Approach to work-

1. Why its not working?

We are calling `https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js` asynchronously(non blocking) to improve the performance. With Async javascript file loading, you are not able to call the gapi method on body load.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var po = document.createElement('script');
            po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    </script>
```

2. To make the api call you first have to know javascript file is successfully loaded.
3. For this you have to call method using callback.
   `https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=makeAPICall`
4. Write an api request & execution it in the callback method to get data.

**Check below example for this-**

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <span id="signinButton">
      <span
        class="g-signin"
        data-callback="signinCallback" 
        data-clientid="YOUR CLIENT ID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
      </span>
    </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">      
      (function() {
         var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
         po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=signinCallback';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
      function signinCallback(authResult) {
            if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
                    document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
                        makeAPICall();
            } else {
                console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
            }
      }
            function makeAPICall(){
            gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
              var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
                'userId': 'me'
              });
              request.execute(function (resp){
                console.log(resp);
                if(resp.id){
                  console.log('ID: ' + resp.id);
                }
                if(resp.displayName){
                  console.log('Display Name: ' + resp.displayName);
                }
                if(resp.image && resp.image.url){
                  console.log('Image URL: ' + resp.image.url);
                }
                if(resp.url){
                  console.log('Profile URL: ' + resp.url);
                }
              });
           });
      }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Conclusion:** Calling javascript API before loading the asynchronously client library.

`To avoid "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.". Call makeAPICall() method only when user is logged in not on every request.`